# how to fetch net worth of a given address?

Tags: balances, external-api, explorer-api

Take this whale wallet for example:

https://etherscan.io/tokenholdings?a=0xa929022c9107643515f5c777ce9a910f0d1e490c

If you look at the top right, it says `Value in USD`.

[image]

Is there any [any API](https://api.etherscan.io/apis) that can help me derive this USD value irrespective of what all ERC20 tokens are in wallet?

APIs so far either need a *contract address* or return *eth valuation*

PS:

- m trying to fetch all this using *python's requests library*
- sorry for wrong tags if any

Comment: did you get the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I had a quick look at a dumb (scraping-based) answer to this, but gave up. So this answer is more of an idea of what not to do, or what to take further.

---

Given you're already using Python, you could have gone one step further and scraped that page with BeautifulSoup. (`pip install beautifulsoup4`)

However, Etherscan is protected by Cloudflare, so you can't just scrape the page directly.
What you can do is use a package such as Cloudscraper. (`pip install cloudscraper -U`)

*However*, the page you're looking at is also dynamically generated, so you can't just scrape the HTML.
What you can do is use a browser driver such as Selenium to programatically create the page and grab the data. (`pip install selenium`)

But then... it'd probably be quicker to find an appropriate API! (Caution: I've noticed different chain explorers will index tokens slightly differently, as well as use different sources for prices. You're unlikely to find a different explorer with exactly the same overall price as Etherscan.)

Comment: any other way? using api?

Comment: It's not part of the Etherscan API unfortunately (https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/accounts). The issue is that different platforms/exchanges will treat certain tokens differently. If the market for a given token isn't big enough, they will consider the token to have no value. So really you need to understand the different markets for a given token, and then work out the net worth of an address. Difficult and subjective!